# Removing other handlers of the element in Jquery using off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fby9ggw/) in which I have two event handlers attached to the `click` event of a button. And my goal is to make the second event handler remove the first one so that only `Hello2` is displayed to the user as he presses the button. I have read here that `off()` method is designed to implement this, but I fail to reach the goal. My guess is that I am using `$(document).on(...` syntax. Any ideas? I have spent half day on this!!

UPDATE:

Put in other words, I want the second event listener to cancel out/deactivate the first one.

Comment: Can't you just use `$(document).off('click', 'button');` before attaching second event handler? because even if you turn off previous event handler from second one, previous ones will execute for at least one before being turned off.

Answer (score 0):

From W3Schools:

```
// Remove the click event for all <p> elements
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").off("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is what you are looking for. But this is one way to do it:

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e){
       alert('hello1');
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
       alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: this is close to what I want to achieve, but I want the LAST listener to cancel out all PREVIOUS listeners. Not vice versa. And I don't want to solve the issue by simply changing the sequence in the code itself